# Restructuring Multi Dimensional Array Format

Tags: php, arrays

I am struggling with what would appear to be a pretty straight forward task. I have looked at and tried all kinds of functions and suggestion on SO hoping that maybe there is something simple and functional out there. Nothing I tried gives me the logic to do the restructuring.

I have a long complex array. However very much simplified the logic problem I am trying to solve generically is as follows:

```
$cost_type = Array
(
    0 => "ISP2",
    1 => "ISP3",
    2 => "ISP4"
);
$supplier_name  = Array
(
    0 => "NAME-A",
    1 => "NAME-B",
    2 => "NAME-C"
 );
$propertyid = Array
(
    0 => "property1",
    1 => "property2",
    2 => "property2"
);
```

and I need to convert it to the following set of arrays (noting the concatenation of the two arrays with a common property id.....

```
 $property1
 (
    array['charges']  
            [0] =>IPS2

   array ['names']
            [0] =>NAME-A
 )

 $property2
 (
   array['charges'] 
           [0] ->IPS3
           [1] =>IPS4

   array['names']
         [0] =>NAME-B
         [1] =>NAME-c
 )
```

I have tried everything over the course of the last few hours and a simple solution totally evades me.

Comment: so you are trying to group all these array by property right?

Comment: yes sir,  These values are all coming in from a group of form selection boxes so the arrays are auto generated by the forms as shown in the first part of the question. But they then need to be loaded to the database with a propertyid filter (hence conversion)

Comment: I can think of a couple solutions to the problem I *think* you're trying to solve, but I don't really know the full scope of the problem or solution based on your original post.

Comment: The problem really does resolve to the example shown. The original problem is just bigger (much more data) that's all DJ. So would really appreciate a lead on any ideas you have

Comment: Can you elaborate on the real data? Not the example, but how it can deviate from it. eg, can there be more properties? Is it always in that order? If there are more, how should the code know how to call them?

Comment: Is the first code block one array with three subarrays or three separate arrays. If the latter, what is the names of them?

Comment: @Andreas the first code block can be set up either way. At the moment it is separate arrays. The names are $cost_type;  $supplier_name and $propertyid. Hope that help a little Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @FirstOne yes there are thousands of possible properties. However the structure of the arrays as above never changes.

Comment: It's hard to grasp how this will be extrapolated to the bigger picture. How can this example vary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can join the three arrays as you say in comments above this code will generate the look you want.
I loop through the array with property and keep key as the key to find names and charges in the other subarrays.

```
$cost_type = Array
(
    0 => "ISP2",
    1 => "ISP3",
    2 => "ISP4"
);
$supplier_name  =Array
(
    0 => "NAME-A",
    1 => "NAME-B",
    2 => "NAME-C"
 );
$propertyid = Array
(
    0 => "property1",
    1 => "property2",
    2 => "property2"
);
$arr[] = $cost_type;
$arr[] = $supplier_name;
$arr[] = $propertyid;

$result = array();
Foreach($arr[2] as $key => $prop){
    $result[$prop]["charges"][] =$arr[0][$key];
    $result[$prop]["names"][] = $arr[1][$key];
}

Var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/EilvE

Comment: That does it. Thank you. Close to a couple of other suggestions deserving a notch up although this one seems the most straight forward.

Comment: You can skip the part that merges the arrays if you want. I wrote that answer before I got your answer in comments so I just edited it to fit. But `$arr[0][$key]` can be replaced with `$cost_type[$key]` and the same with $supplier_name. And that means the foreach loops `$propertyid` instead. But the result is going to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The following code converts the original array in the expected result:

```
$res = array();
foreach($arr[2] as $k => $foo){ // foreach property
    if(!isset($res[$foo])){ // add property if not yet in list
        $res[$foo] = array(
            'charges' => array($arr[0][$k]),
            'names' => array($arr[1][$k])
        );
    }else{ // add new value to already existing property
        $res[$foo]['charges'][] = $arr[0][$k];
        $res[$foo]['names'][] = $arr[1][$k];
    }
}
```

Check it out here: https://eval.in/904473

Of course, it assumes a bunch on things about the data, but it should work for any number of items.

And if you need the property in another variable, just access it with `$res['name of it]`.

Comment: thank you. Your answer is very similar to Andreas who beat you to it by a whisker. I marked you ulp though. Again thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
        Run this code you will get smiler result as you want :
           $twodimantion=array();
$properties=array('property1','property2','property3');
$charges=array('ISP2','ISP3','ISP4');
$names=array('NAME-A','NAME-B','NAME-C');
foreach ($properties as $key => $property) {
       $twodimantion['charge'][$key]=$charges[$key];
       $twodimantion['names'][$key]=$names[$key];
       $twoarray[$property]=$twodimantion;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($twoarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: It's not for me. But it's more correct than before. But you are missing an `;` and the output is still wrong. Prop2 should not have isp2. https://3v4l.org/g52YF edit i see you found the `;`

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I completely follow what you are trying to do, but I think this may be part of the way there for you.

When trying to restructure data in PHP, it's often helpful to create a empty array (or other data structure) to store the new data in first.  Then you find a way to loop over your initial data structure that allows you to insert items into your reformatted structure in the right sequence.

```
<?php
$properties = []; // Array to hold final result

// Loop over your initial inputs
foreach ($groupsOfValues as $groupName => $groupValues) {
    $temp = [];  // Array to hold each groupings reformatted data

    // Loop over the items in one of the inputs
    for ($i=0; $i<count($group) && $i<count($properties)+1; $i++) {
        if (!is_array($temp[$groupName])) {
             $temp[$groupName] = [];
        }
        $temp[$groupName][] = $group[$i];
    }

    $properties[] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: _Unexpected `{` in ..._. You missed a `)` in the condition.

Comment: Having difficulty relating this to the problem to be honest. The principles are standard. The solution,,,cant really see how it applies just now. Bit more explanation would really help